# How to see which python scripts are running?

Tags: windows, windows-10, python

I ran the command `tasklist | FIND "python"` and got

[image: tasklist output]

How do I see the actual script that's being run?

Answer (score 0):

If the script was specified on the Python command-line, you may see
that by using the free
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

When it's running, right-click any column header and select
"Select columns...".
Go to the "Process image" tab, place a check-mark next to
"Command Line" and click OK. You may also add or remove other columns
or reorder selected columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell instead

```powershell
(Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "Name='python.exe' OR Name='python3.exe'").Commandline
```

The `OR` condition here is just an example for you to create more complex queries. Of course you can shorten it to something like

```powershell
(gwmi win32_process -F "Name like 'python%'").Commandline
```

or

```powershell
(gwmi win32_process -F "CommandLine LIKE '%yourscript.py%'").Commandline
```

`%` is the [wildcard character for matching any strings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-the-like-operator-to-simplify-your-wql-queries/) in the WQL language

In modern Windows you can and should replace `Get-WmiObject` by `Get-CimInstance`

You can also add a custom `CommandLine` property to the `Diagnostics.Process` class by [adding the below to your `$PROFILE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66735209/995714)

```powershell
$TypeData = @{
    TypeName   = [System.Diagnostics.Process].ToString()
    MemberType = [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberTypes]::ScriptProperty
    MemberName = 'CommandLine'
    Value = {
        if (('Win32NT' -eq [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Platform)) { # it's windows
            (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $($this.Id)").CommandLine
        } elseif (('Unix' -eq [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Platform)) { # it's linux/unix
            Get-Content -LiteralPath "/proc/$($this.Id)/cmdline"
        } elseif (('MacOSX' -eq [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Platform)) { # it's macos
            # ???
        }
    }
}
Update-TypeData @TypeData -ErrorAction Ignore
```

then use it like this

```powershell
(Get-Process python).Commandline
```

---

If you want to do that from cmd then use [`wmic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic)

```powershell
wmic process where "name like 'python%'" get processid,commandline
wmic process where "Commandline like '%python%'" get processid,commandline
```